# Can I get the current queue in perform method of worker with sidekiq/redis?

Tags: redis, queue, sidekiq, worker

I want to be able to delete all job in queue, but I don't know what queue is it. I'm in perform method of my worker and I need to get the "current queue", the queue where the current job is come from.

for this time I use :

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new
queue.each do |job|
  job.delete
end
```

because I just use "default queue", It's work.

But now I will use many queues and I can't specify only one queue for this worker because I need use a lots for a server load balancing.

So how I can get the queue where we are in perform method?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't by design, that's orthogonal context to the job.  If your job needs to know a queue name, pass it explicitly as an argument.

This is much faster:

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new.clear
```

Answer (score 1):

These [docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers) show that you can access all running job information wwhich includes the `jid` (job ID) and queue name for each job

inside the `perform` method you have access to the jid with the `jid` accessor. From that you can find the current job and get the queue name

```
workers = Sidekiq::Workers.new
this_worker = workers.find { |_, _, work|
  work['payload']['jid'] == jid
}
queue = this_worker[2]['queue']
```

however, the content of Sidekiq::Workers can be up to 5 seconds out of date, so you should only try this after your worker has been running at least 5 seconds, which may not be ideal